# Can epdf change pdf?

Tags: luatex

I want to edit PDF using the epdf library included in LuaTeX (add, bleed/crop/trim box). I can get current trim size of the PDF (if it's set) via epdf **PDFRectangle**. But I didn't find defined methods to set/change thees boxes. I know that epdf is still in a development stage, but maybe there are implemented (but not documented) methods?

luatex version 0.74.

Comment: @JosephWright epdf is part of LuaTeX, but I guess you know that. In that sense I think the question is perfectly valid, although I don't know the answer.

Comment: I don't know about version 0.74, but the manual of version 0.70 is pretty clear in saying that the epdf library is "read only".

Comment: I did what I need with python (**pyPdf** module). But I hope with luatex epdf module I will can do all thees modifications to.

Comment: As of version 0.76, the EPDF library is still read only.

Answer (score 4):

At the current time (release 0.76) the LuaTeX manual states explicitly that epdf is read-only and has 'alpha' status. As such, the answer is currently 'no, you cannot do this'.